# selenium WebDriver.dll download for the PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

I need the WebDriver.dll for the webpage automation using powershell. when I try to install the file from https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/ [image]

The downloaded Zip file contain only below files
[image]

Please guide me to get Webdriver.dll file.

Comment: Have you tried installing the packages ?

Answer (score 0):

If you extract the `.nupkg` files from the zip archive to the file system, you can then open each `.nupkg` as a zip archive itself. `Selenium.WebDriver.dll` is in the `Selenium.WebDriver` .nupkg file.